# Taking this point into account/ taking into account this point

Tags: sentence-construction, word-order, syntax

I have read in many dictionaries that **taking *something* into account** is the rule for constructing expressions that contain this one. However, in some cases I have seen that **taking into account *something*** is also used. So I am wondering if, in fact, both patterns of construction are equally valid in any case.

For instance, are the following two sentences equally valid? I mean, are they both grammatically correct?

1. Taking into account this point, I would say the statement is false.
2. Taking this point into account, I would say the statement is false.

Comment: Taking something into account sounds better than taking into account something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither. The first problem is in 1. "Taking into account this point." You first have to say **what** you want to take into account. And, in 2. "I would the statement is false." What about the statement? You say it is false. So, a better way to say it is, "Taking this point into account, I would say the statement is false."

But how **I** would say it, is "Considering this point, I would say the statement is false."

Comment: But you can also say "Taking into account, this point, I would say the statement is false."

Answer (score 1):

If “something” is relatively short and simple, I’d prefer “taking something into account”.

If it’s longer and/or complicated, there is a risk of “into account” becoming ambiguous or confusing, which can be solved by “taking into account something”.

- Taking his age into account, ...
- Taking into account his age and how that will affect what discounts he is eligible for, ...